# How to program in OOP by C# in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I am beginner in C# and learning in .NET CORE in Mac and Linux. I can not use Windows ambient in this moment. I'm test the similar features with other languages, something like variables, loops, structure control, and others features. However, I need get acquainted with Oriented Objects Programming in C#. The tutorials searched in Internet, supposes my ambient with Windows and Visual Studio, and it teacher basic concepts OOP, and not my specific problem (do it in .NET CORE).

This is my code:

```
using System;

namespace hwapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           objeto c = new Program();
           c.numero = 12;
           c.titular = "João";
           c.saldo = 102;

           Console.WriteLine("Número: "+c.numero+"\n");
           Console.WriteLine("Titular da conta: "+c.titular+"\n");
           Console.WriteLine("Salto: "+c.saldo+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Its a message in console:

> Program.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'objeto'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) [/home/upgrade/dotnet/hwapp/hwapp.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

I am not a native in English language, I am Brazilian. Sorry for some grammatical errors!

Comment: use `var c`. `object` wont have the properties you are trying to assign. other wise create a new class to hold the values you want.

Comment: Is possible create Class into other class?

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff yes is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic gist is that you are trying to assign properties/fields that do not exist on the object you are using.

In this case you want to add a class to hold the values you want stored.

```
using System;

namespace hwapp {
    public static class Program {

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Example c = new Example {
                Numero = 12,
                Titular = "João",
                Saldo = 102,
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Número: {c.Numero}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Titular da conta: {c.Titular}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Salto: {c.Saldo}");
        }
    }

    public class Example {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Titular { get; set; }
        public int Saldo { get; set; }
    }

}
```